# Start an Application on recieving a Text Message

Tags: android

I have done a small app that locks the screen. But this happens only when i open the app and click my lock button.

I want to do that by sending a TextMessage. That is if I send a txt "Lock" from a pre stored number It should do the the wokr of my buttons OnClick Listener

Can Anyone guide me how to start off with it ?

being new to android I have no idea how to start off with this

Comment: please post some code that you've tried.

Comment: Do you specify a message as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
  public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
 {

String message ; 
boolean check_message ; 
String senderNUM ; 
static String H ; 
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {

   //---get the SMS message passed in---
      final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    senderNUM = senderNum ; 
                    message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    H = currentMessage.getMessageBody(); 
                   // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                                 "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);

                    toast.show();
                    if(i==0)
                        H = currentMessage.getMessageBody(); 


                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

        check_message = message_checked(H) ; 

       //---display the new SMS message---
        if(check_message)
        {
            abortBroadcast();



       Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
       intentHome.putExtra("msgContent", message);

       intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentHome);
        }
        else 
            System.exit(0); 

   }                         

  public boolean message_checked(String the_message)
   {
String Code = new String("*%#&"); 
String four_char = "" ; 
for(int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++)
{
    four_char += the_message.charAt(i) ; 

}
if(four_char.equals(Code))
{


    return true;
}
else 
    return false ; 



  }

 }
```